# What is the difference between "I think ........." VS "I just think .........."?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, semantics

This is from an interview with a celebrity where she is asked many questions in a short period of time. At some point, in between two questions, the reporter says to her:

**"You were valedictorian of your class. That wasn't a question. I just think that is great."**

The beginning of the last sentence **"I just think ...."** drew my attention. I wondered why he simply did not say **"I think...."** but **"I just think .....".**

So, I focused on what the difference would be between **"I think ...."** VS **"I just think....."**,

I think he added **"just"** because he remembered that fact(being valedictorian) a little while ago, so he added **"just"** to mean a short while ago, as in **"I have just finished my lunch."**

But then I also think he might have said it for something else, like maybe to refer to his astonishment, or her being so humble about it, etc.

I  am not quite sure which one.

So, I wanted to ask, what difference does it make when one says **"I just think that is great."** instead of **"I think that is great."?**

Comment: "Just" here means "merely"

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there are two possibilities here. The first (which I consider more likely) is that the interviewer means "only". In the previous sentence, the interviewer said "that wasn't a question", so he or she is suggesting that in the current sentence "only" means what it says and doesn't have any other purpose (such as asking a question). [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just) has the following definition:

> 3a: ONLY, SIMPLY
> | *just* last year
> | *just* be yourself

The interviewer might also be using "just" for emphasis, in which case it would be similar to "really". [The Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just) says:

> You use **just** to emphasize the following word or phrase, in order to express feelings such as annoyance, admiration, or certainty.
> [emphasis]
> *She just won't relax.
>
> I knew you'd be here. I just knew.
>
> Isn't it fantastic? Just look at that!
>
> Just think, we should be home this time tomorrow.
>
> I don't see the point in it really. It's just stupid.
>
> Isn't he just the most beautiful thing you ever saw?*

Answer (score 0):

Adding "just" *might* make the statement more tentative, or *might* indicate *mild* disagreement, but it depends on **context**.

```
Q: "Don't you realize he's wrong?" A: "I just think there's another way to view it."

Q: "Want to go on a picnic?" A: "I just think it might rain."
```

Comment: What you say is correct, but probably not relevant to the sentence in the question.